# How to change SelectedIndex property on slave ListBox, when SelectedIndex changed in main ListBox in WPF via XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I'm newbie in WPF and I have a simple question.

I have a two ListBox, first list box provide data to second list box. How I can  select first item in second list box (change SelectedIndex property to "0"), via **XAML**, when this property changed in first list box? Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you want to **bind** to `SelectedIndex` but your question is unclear. What **exactly** are you trying to achieve? Can you provide an example?

Comment: **[Look at this image](http://s32.postimg.org/nxjfi27wl/bindingstest.png)**.

"Markets" list box provide data for "Items" list box, "Items" list box, provide data for "item info" control. When I'm selecting something in markets list box, items list box is updating too, but it don't select first item, and "item info" is empty. How I can select first item in "Items" list box, when "Markets" list box SelectedIndex change?

P.S.: sorry for my poor english.